# Types should be the same but are not

Tags: c++, types, type-systems

I am not sure I understand why the first test evaluates to true and the second to false. I know that the information from `typeid().name()` is usually not reliable, but my main problem is with the `typeid` itself. I don't understand why the type of `*test` is not `Location<1>`, or what else is wrong. Any thoughts? Is there same wrapper around a type here that I don't see? Thanks in advance, and apologies if the answer is obvious.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

class LocationAbstract
{
    virtual void get_() = 0;
};

template<int i>
class Location : public LocationAbstract
{
public:
    static constexpr int test = i;
    
    virtual void get_() override
    {
        return;
    }
};

template <int i>
Location<i> LocationGenerator()
{
    Location<i> test{};
    
    return test;
    
}

int main()
{
    LocationAbstract *table[10];
    
    table[0] = new decltype(LocationGenerator<0>());
    table[1] = new decltype(LocationGenerator<1>());
    
    Location<1> *test;
    
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Casting\n";
        test = dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1]);
    }
    catch (std::bad_cast &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Bad cast\n";
    }
    
    // test1, evaluates to true
    std::cout << (typeid(*test) == typeid(*dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1]))) << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(*test).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(*dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1])).name() << "\n----\n";
    
    // test2, why does this evaluate to false while the above evaluates to true ?
    std::cout << (typeid(Location<1>()) == typeid(*dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1]))) << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid((Location<1>())).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(*dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1])).name() << "\n";

    auto test1 = Location<1>();
    auto test2 = *dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1]);
    
    std::cout << typeid(test1).name() << " and " << typeid(test2).name() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably not relevant, but you should initialize `test` or else the operator will read an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 3):

An extra set of `()` makes all the difference here.  In `typeid(Location<1>())` and `typeid((Location<1>()))`, `Location<1>()` actually means two totally different things.

In `typeid(Location<1>())`, `Location<1>()` is interpreted as a function type that returns a `Location<1>` and takes no parameters.

In `typeid((Location<1>()))`, `Location<1>()` is interpreted as value-initializing an anonymous `Location<1>` object.

The `typeid` operator can work on either types or expressions.  That is, you can say `typeid(int)` as well as `typeid(42)`.  Since `Location<1>()` *can* be interpreted as a type, the language does so.  `(Location<1>())` cannot be interpreted as a type though, so it must be interpreted as an expression.  The only thing `Location<1>()` can mean as part of an expression is to value-initialize an anonymous `Location<1>` object, so `typeid` gives you the type of that object.

---

Let this be yet another reason to prefer uniform-initialization syntax when creating temporary objects; `Location<1>{}` would not have this ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear and useful. I remember reading about this ambiguity once, but I completely forgot about it (and I did not really face the problem before). Yes, I really should use uniform initialization syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Examine these two lines:

```
std::cout << (typeid(Location<1>()) == typeid(*dynamic_cast<Location<1>*>(table[1]))) << "\n";
std::cout << typeid((Location<1>())).name() << "\n";
```

In the first line, you use `typeid(Location<1>())`. `typeid` can take types as well as expressions, and `Location<1>()` is a function type with no parameters and a return type of `Location<1>`.

So why does the name print the same? That's because of the second line: `typeid((Location<1>()))`. By wrapping the argument in parentheses, it is no longer a valid type, so it is treated as an expression and the name of `typeid(Location<1>)` is printed. Removing the extra parentheses prints `F8LocationILi1EEvE` under the same mangling scheme.

To avoid the ambiguity, you can also use the type directly (`typeid(Location<1>)`) or use braces: `typeid(Location<1>{})`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, as I replied in the comment before I completely forgot about it (and did not really run into those problems before). I should really switch in a consistent way to uniform initialization.